# I am using the openpyxl library on python on a windows 10 computer and trying to load_workbook with whitespace

Tags: python, windows, path, whitespace, openpyxl

I am using the openpyxl library on python 3.5 on a windows 10 computer and trying to load_workbook() an pathname with white space.

I have looked it up online and can't seem to solve this myself. I have included some of my attempts below.

I must be missing something completely, because I can't find anyone else asking about this particular issue with openpyxl.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

My current work around would be to use python to check and possibly rename the file to remove the spaces, but that just seems entirely unnecessary and i might not always have the permissions to do that.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os

docName = "space book.xlsx"
docNameWithExits = "space^ book.xlsm"
fullPathOfDocument =  "./" + docName
fullPathOfDocumentExtraPar = "'" + "./" + docName + "'"
fullOsPath =  os.path.join("." , docName)
docObject = open(fullPathOfDocument,"rb")

try:
    attempt1 = load_workbook(docName)
    print("worked")
except:
    print("didnt work")

try:
    attempt2 = load_workbook(fullPathOfDocument)
    print("worked")
except:
    print("didnt work")

try:
    attempt3 = load_workbook(fullPathOfDocumentExtraPar)
    print("worked")
except:
    print("didnt work")

try:
    attempt4 = load_workbook(docNameWithExits)
    print("worked")
except:
    print("didnt work")

try:
    attempt5 = load_workbook(fullOsPathvar)
    print("worked")
except:
    print("didnt work")

try:
    attempt6 = load_workbook(docObject)
    print("worked")
except:
    print("The computer has won")
```

Thank you in advance for any help
Regards, 
-Nex

Answer (score 1):

openpyxl.load_workbook() can read a path with Whitespace in it. In my fully reproducible example, there's whitespace in the workbook name and the folders.

I'm guessing that the problems occur if you are not preceding your strings with an "r".  The "r" will tell python to treat the given string as a raw string.

```
import os
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Path to be created - please change to your desired folder location
path = r"C:\Users\doe_j\test\python\a path\with spaces"
wb_name = path + r"\space book.xlsx"

if os.path.isdir(path) != True:
    os.makedirs(path)
    print(path, "created!")
elif os.path.isdir(path) != False:
    print(path, "already exists!") 


# making a workbook so this example is reproducible
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws["A1"] = "Putting some text in"

wb.save(wb_name)

# loading that same workbook 
wb = load_workbook(wb_name)
ws = wb.active

ws["A3"] = "Adding Some more text in"

wb.save(wb_name)
```

This example was tested on windows 10, python 3.5 and openpyxl 2.4.7.

Comment: Oh thank you so much!
I am not sure what was wrong. I think it was referring to the programs path with "./"
but i just use os.path.join(os.getcwd(),fileName)
./ had worked previously until i used the document name with spaces


Using your code as an example I got it to work for an arbitrary document with spaces in the path

Thank you for the time for the solution 

but now load_workbook is looking for a zip file on the actual file i care about. I think the XML structure is different because it was output from an SQL database.... The journey continues

Thank you again